# How to run .sh file by click in Xubuntu?

Tags: executable, sh

We should type ./file.sh in terminal to run sh. Is there way to run it as executable file by double click ?

Comment: Still a dupe. One of the answers there is specifically for xfce.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** The question was edited to add "Xubuntu" after this answer was posted. This answer refers to plain Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.

You did not tell us, so I assume that you are running Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. By default, the file manager *will not* allow running scripts by double clicking them. To change this behavior:

1. Open the file manager.
2. Click on the "Files" label on the top-left of the screen. A menu will drop down.
3. Click "Preferences". A tabbed dialog box will be displayed.
4. Select the "Behavior" tab.
5. Choose your preferred behavior for "executable text files" aka scripts.

[image: File manager preferences]

Comment: How about Xubuntu (Thunar file manager doesn't have it) ?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use Xubuntu.

Comment: you'd better use it, GNOME 3 eats a lot and gives nothing in return for that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on it and tick the box permitting it to be an executable. Then you can simply double click, you will get a pop up asking whether to execute it or not.

Comment: I don't have such, in file properties it's marked "allow file run as program". I think it has all necessary permissions: -rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 6844 Jun 12 16:48 idea.sh

Comment: Even after running `chmod +x ./file.sh` ?