# Ubuntu 18.04 executable not executing

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to create a simple 'double click' executable to open a large number of specific folders and applications for a user uncomfortable with using the terminal.

The script is simple enough and works as expected when running through the terminal with the following command:

```
python3 /home/xxxx/Desktop/setup.py
```

When I double click the file, it opens in the text editor.

I have added executable permission with:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/xxxx/Desktop/setup.py
```

...and I've given ample permission with:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/xxxx/Desktop/setup.py
```

...and it has what I think is the appropriate shebang at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

I would expect to see a pop up which asks something like "Do you want to run this as an executable?" but this pop up doesn't appear.

I tried "open with another application" but I found no way to actually open with the terminal or python directly from there.

Getting desperate, I tried to just create a desktop short cut:

```
lxshortcut -o /home/xxxx/Desktop/setup.py
```

...but even this didn't work. The .Desktop file created would only open as a text file.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance for any help/ideas.

Extra Info:

the script doesn't need to be executable from another computer

python3 is installed

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051275/616021). By default, the file manager does not allow execution of scripts. To change this behavior, open Preferences (click on Files at top-left of the screen), select the tab "Behavior" and change the setting for executable text files.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed instruction! I had looked for this before but only in the system settings. Now it works 

Comment: Please get out of the habit of using `sudo` to manipulate files in your own home directory