# Shell scripts not executing

Tags: scripts, 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 but my .sh files will not execute they just open up in gedit. I have tried changing what the file opens with but Idk which application to choose from the list.

Comment: If you are referring to executing scripts from the file manager, then see [Ubuntu 18.04 executable not executing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051478/ubuntu-18-04-executable-not-executing)

Comment: I looked at that and it does not help me that well, I changed the preference to Ask waht to do, but the Shell script still just opens gedit

Answer (score 5):

First, ensure your script begins with the correct hash-bang, e.g. `#!/bin/bash`

Then make sure the *.sh* file is executable -

1. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or from the applications menu
2. Navigate to the location of the *.sh* file. e.g. `cd ~/location/to/my/file`
3. Run

   1. `chmod u+x <file name>.sh`, or
   2. if permission is an issue, `sudo chmod u+x <file name>.sh` and enter your password to confirm
4. Alternatively, you can right-click the *.sh* file from the file browser and update permissions via the `Properties` option

To make *.sh* files executable from nautilus(file browser) follow these steps:

Referring - [How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?](http://How%20to%20execute%20a%20script%20just%20by%20double%20clicking%20like%20.EXE%20files%20in%20Windows?)

1. Install dconf-editor because it isn't installed by default.
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `dconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. In `dconf-editor` goto: `org` ➤ `gnome` ➤ `nautilus` ➤ `preferences`
4. Click on `executable-text-activation` and from drop down menu and  select:

   1. **launch**: to launch scripts as programs, OR
   2. **ask**: to ask what to do via a dialog.
5. Close `dconf-editor`.

(**Source**: [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus) Answer courtesy of *Basharat Sial*)

Comment: I think that in point 3 should be "dconf-editor" instead of "dconf-editor" :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions for the file:

`ls -l FILENAME`

If the first 4 characters of output aren't `-rwx` then change the permissions on the file:

`chmod 744 FILENAME`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `.sh` files are marked as executable (have "executable" permission).  This is the primary way that a lot of software uses to tell if a file is an executable you want to run or a document you want to open.